# How to move every 4 elements to another container with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this markup:

```
<section class="oldContainer">
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</section>
<section class="newContainer"></section>
<section class="newContainer"></section>
```

And I'd like to move all `<article>'s` from `oldContainer` to `newContainer`, but so that the `newContainer` can have no more than 4 `<article>'s` each. How can this be done with jQuery? I only know how to wrap elements in this situation, but not move them :)

Comment: Get all the elements from `oldcontainer`, iterate over them, create html for the `newContainer`, `remove` from `oldcontainer` and insert in `newContainer`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the newcontainer elements are already present then, you could just move them

```js
var $as = $('.oldContainer article');
$('.newContainer').each(function(i) {
  $(this).append($as.slice(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4))
});
```

```css
.oldContainer {
  min-height: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.newContainer {
  min-height: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="oldContainer">
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
</section>
<section class="newContainer"></section>
<section class="newContainer"></section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `appendTo` to move the `article` in `.newContainer`

```
var i = 0; // To get the .newContainer by index

// Run until there is no article left in .oldContainer
while ($('.oldContainer article').length) {
    $('.oldContainer article:lt(4)').appendTo($('.newContainer').eq(i++));

    // Get first four `article` and move it to the .newContainer element
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/as25njhm/)